# qTip2 styling result is different than intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, qtip2

I'm brand new to jQuery and through searching around and finding examples I've got the [qTip2](http://qtip2.com/) plugin presenting data in a way I really like. Please see: http://tcb.cbmiweb.com/foundation/test1.html. At the bottom, please hover the link ***levels of service*** to expose the table data in a persistent tooltip.

[image: Good tooltip on test1.html page]

I know generally what is happening here and I like the styling of the display (especially the fonts, alternating shades for the rows and the border). I've searched around and cannot how this is done. I suspect this: `<tr data-browser="ie" class="odd gradeX">` helps achieve the result but not sure.

Most importantly, however, is my failure to get the same result on a related page (please see: http://tcb.cbmiweb.com/UIForms/Subscribing.aspx# - again hovering over the link ***levels of service***.

[image: this is the problem tooltip appearance]

When I look at my code, both pages should be the same but clearly they are not. Outputs are the same on Chrome, FF, and IE11 and I've poked around a bit with Developer Tools.

In summary, my goal is to make the tooltip for this on the "Subscribing" page look as good as it does on the first page (test1.html). Please help me on this.

E D I T - U P D A T E: adding code snippets related to test1.html (the desired look):

```
    #pricetable th td{
    text-align:center;
}
.myInlineQtipCenter{
    text-align:center;
}
.myCustomClass{
    border-color: rgb(0,190,0);
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.myCustomClass .qtip-content{
    font-size: 18px;
}
.myContainer {
    background-color: #FCF6CF;    
    /* width:100%; */
    border: 5px solid white;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
}
.tooltiptext{
    display: none;
}
```

**Markup inside test1.html:**

```
<a id="myLink" href="#">levels of service</a>
    <div class="tooltiptext">
        <table id="pricetable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="myInlineQtipCenter">Edition</th>
                    <th class="myInlineQtipCenter">Maximum Users</th>
                    <th class="myInlineQtipCenter">Annual Cost</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr data-browser="ie" class="odd gradeX">
                    <td class="myInlineQtipCenter">Home</td>
                    <td class="myInlineQtipCenter">2</td>
                    <td class="myInlineQtipCenter">$36.00</td>
                </tr>                               
                <tr data-browser="ie" class="odd gradeX">
                    <td class="myInlineQtipCenter">Small Business</td>
                    <td class="myInlineQtipCenter">5</td>
                    <td class="myInlineQtipCenter">$120.00</td>
                </tr>                               
                <tr data-browser="ie" class="odd gradeX">
                    <td class="myInlineQtipCenter">Enterprise</td>
                    <td class="myInlineQtipCenter">unlimited</td>
                    <td class="myInlineQtipCenter">$250.00</td>
                </tr>                               
            </tbody>
        </table>                                
    </div>
```

**Script at bottom of test1.html:**

```
    $('a#myLink').each(function() {
        $(this).qtip({
            content: {
                text: $(this).next(".tooltiptext"),
                title: { text: 'Service level pricing:',button: true}
            }
            ,
            style: {classes: 'qtip-youtube qtip-close myCustomClass'} 
            ,
            position: { 
                my: 'top left',  
                at: 'bottom center'
            }
            ,
            events: {
                hide: function (event, api) { 
                    if (event.originalEvent.type !== 'click')
                        return false;
                }
        }
        });
    });
```

Again, the above code on the test1.html page works as I would like. Code on the "problem" page is almost exactly the same. How to make the 2nd tooltip output be like the first. I hope this makes my question clear and someone reverses the DownVote. I am not trying to be lazy. I can post more code from the problem page.

Comment: The levels of service tooltip is working for me on chrome... I think o.O

Comment: I was a huge fan of qTip2 but find styling them tedious, cumbersome, and inconsistent across browsers.  I've since moved to Tooltipster which is a whole lot easier out of the box.

Comment: @Michel - thanks for your efforts so far. By the comments you added when inserting images, I think you misunderstood me. Now the first image from test1.html shows the "good" tooltip with the "zebra" stripes and fonts. The 2nd image you added shows the whole screen and the black tooltip inside shows no zebra stripes, etc. I have no idea how the stripes got there and if I knew more about that perhaps I could reproduce the look on the Subscribing page.

Comment: @Sparky, thanks for your time. I have consistency across browsers but I wonder about the CSS classes "odd" and "gradeX" which I have because the example I copied used them. Do you know the origin of these classes? I suspect they give me the good zebra stripes but I am lost on that appearance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem using Chrome Developer Tools. In short, the "problem" display lacked reference to foundation.css where a TABLE selector (and other CSS rules) accounts for the differences. [image: CSS Differences here]

According to foundation.css, table has a white background, etc. The left hand pane shows how pricetable is inflenced by this css. The problem display on the right hand pane shows how without the foundation.css rule for table element there are inherent differences.

I will ponder how to fix this properly without too many ripple effects on the .aspx pages. The origin of this issue stemmed from poor site design at the beginning of the ASP.Net webforms project, especially with regard to CSS. In hindsight, I wish I could withdraw the question; I just needed to study Chrome Developer tools more deeply and use it to find discrepancies.